# When I install SharePoint 2016 on Windows Server 2016 with AutoInstaller, error while register managed account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, windows, windows-server-2016

Today I faced an issue, when I tried to install SharePoint 2016 on Windows Server 2016 with AutoInstaller scripts.

### Error says:

Registering managed account "DOMAIN\Service Account""1...
New-SPManagedAccount : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
At D:\AutoSPInstaller\AutoSPInstallerModule.psm1:2258 char:17
+                 New-SPManagedAccount -Credential $credAccount | Out-N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...wManagedAccount:SPCmdletNewManagedAccount) [New-SPManage
   dAccount], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewManagedAccount

---

- Script halted!

Exception             : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:    - Failed to create managed account
TargetObject          :    - Failed to create managed account
CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (   - Failed to create managed account:String) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId :    - Failed to create managed account
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at AddManagedAccounts, D:\AutoSPInstaller\AutoSPInstallerModule.psm1: line 2259
                        at Set-FarmConfig, D:\AutoSPInstaller\AutoSPInstallerMain.ps1: line 214
                        at , D:\AutoSPInstaller\AutoSPInstallerMain.ps1: line 429
                        at , : line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}

### PSMessageDetails      :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have a problem with reading the account. Try this process to resolve it:

1. Go into Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in
2. Click View…Advanced Features on the menu
3. Find my service account in the directory
4. Right-click on it and select Properties from the menu
5. Click on the Security tab
6. Click on Authenticated Users in the top part of the dialog
7. Check the Read box in the Allow column
8. Click the OK button to save the changes

Comment: Thank you @Marek Sarad. Is this one time task? Because, this  Service Account which we got error were already member of another SharePoint Farm Admin group.

Comment: Yes it is one time task. The account was probably wrongly set up.

Comment: But, In existed SharePoint 2013 Farm we are using the same service account as Farm Admin.

Comment: Maybe when the 2013 farm was set up the permission could be read, hard to say without accessing the AD.